# How to fix cannot find libgcc.a: No such file or directory error

Tags: android, gcc, coffeescript, kernel, libgcc

I'm trying to make a standalone compile of the kernel for my android phone, using Google Toolchain, and have already tried Uber and linarc.

All of them give the same error, which I don't understand:

```
/home/aayushgupta219/kernel/toolchain64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld: cannot find libgcc.a: No such file or directory
/home/aayushgupta219/kernel/toolchain64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld: cannot find libgcc.a: No such file or directory
Makefile:814: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

Here is a copy of the [source](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_asus_msm8916).

Here is a copy of the [logfile](https://hastebin.com/uhihohekux.coffeescript)

Comment: Do you find libgcc.a inside your Toolchain installation? It should reside in some lib/<target>/<GCC Version> folder.

Comment: It is present there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. In case anyone is having same error and finding no fix here is my own fix for it. I was on Ubuntu 16.04 having gcc5 and was getting this error. I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 with gcc6 preinstalled and now no more such errors.

Answer (score 0):

-Fist of all
use command
`gcc -m32 -print-libgcc-file-name`.
then use
`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential gdb git vim`
`sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`
if it dosent work.

-Second
`gcc -m32 -print-libgcc-file-name` will give you a path that include libgcc.a.
just copy that to this place.
that path is `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/32/libgcc.a`in my computer
use `cp /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/32/libgcc.a  ./`

Comment: Copy to what place?